Python "Inputimeout" not working as expected
So I'm trying to build a simple typing speed test. It takes the input for 60 seconds and calculates typing speed and accuracy. I used "inputimeout" to try achieve the objectives, however, the variable "text", which should contain the timed input from the user, cannot be used in other parts of the program; it causes an error stating that "text" was not assigned.
This is just one part of the code. This should be where the error is
def text_receiver():
    try:
        text = inputimeout(prompt = "Type the above in one minute:  ", timeout = 60)
    except Exception:
        print("Time's up! ")
        
    return text


This is the error
 local variable 'text' referenced before assignment


if the error is quite obvious, I apologize as I haven't written much codes with "try except" and inputimeout

If the exception is thrown, text never gets created. Move return text into the try block.

As said, if an exception is thrown, the variable text is not instantiated. Put the return text into the try block or initialize the variable text before the try block to make sure it exists when you return it.

as the error said, give the variable a value before return, i.e.
def return_text():
    try: 
  
    # Take timed input using inputimeout() function 
        time_over = inputimeout(prompt='Type the above in one minute:  ', timeout=60) 
  
    # Catch the timeout error 
    except Exception: 
  
    # Declare the timeout statement 
        time_over = 'Time's up! '
    return (time_over) 

print(return_text())

